# attribute error (key) in sqlalchemy-flask application, cant connect to database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow.  Im in a data science bootcamp and I missed a class and I am going through the recording and trying to follow along with the instructor showing us how to reference a sqlite database in a flask app, but I cant get the example running.  Im able to run flask apps that dont reference sqlite though.  For example, when i try and run python code that begins with this:

```
import numpy as np

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func

from flask import Flask, jsonify


#################################################
# Database Setup
#################################################
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///titanic.sqlite")

# reflect an existing database into a new model
Base = automap_base()
# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

# Save reference to the table
Passenger = Base.classes.passenger

#################################################
# Flask Setup
#################################################
app = Flask(__name__)
```

im greeted with an error that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\frcon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 210, in __getattr__
    return self._data[key]
KeyError: 'passenger'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/frcon/Desktop/pythonstuff/RU-JER-DATA-PT-01-2020/01-Lesson-Plans/10-Advanced-Data-Storage-and-Retrieval/3/Activities/10-Ins_Flask_with_ORM/Solved/app.py", line 22, in <module>
    Passenger = Base.classes.passenger
  File "C:\Users\frcon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 212, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: passenger
```

I guess it means that it cant find the "passenger" table but im sure it exists, I checked the database.  In the recording of class, my professor was able to run this code without modifying anything.  Any help is super appreciate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is the passenger table spelled the same in `titanic.sqlite` file they way you are referencing it?

You can run the following in jupyter notebook with the same dependencies.

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///titanic.sqlite")
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

# This should return the table names
Base.classes.keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that i needed to import os :)

Answer (score 0):

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///titanic.sqlite")

The issue is in above line:
add full path like "c:/user/myname/desktop/myapp/titanic.sqlite" instead of just "titanic.sqlite"